# What is the difference between Taylor series and Laurent series?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Can someone intuitively describe what is the  difference between Taylor series and Laurent series? Also, what is the most general formula for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laurent series allows for terms with negative power. Intuitively, this allows for singularities to occur.